# Programmatic Requests to Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, curl, google-identity-toolkit

I'm working on a webapp that uses Google Identity Toolkit for login. We're coming to a point where we need to perform load tests and we definitely want our tests to encompass the whole of our system flow; we want to make sure GITKit doesn't end up being a bottleneck.

However, since GITKit seems to be only useable as a front end component, we haven't been able to figure out a way to include GITKit either in load tests or unit tests, instead extracting Google's GTokens from server logs after a human user has logged in and placing them in an accessible location until expiration, at which point they are replaced.

This has been very cumbersome, and it certainly won't work for load testing where we need to sprout thousands of users at the same time.

Does anyone know a way to programmatically make requests to a GITKit server/log in with GITKit, either through the command line or in a language (preferably python). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Identity Toolkit has a REST API that you can call from your server: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/verifyPassword. A Google server API Key is needed in the request URL like https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key={YOUR_API_KEY}. You can refer to [this page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490) to obtain an API Key from Google Developer Console.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. The verify password route itself requires some kind of candidate token from a different provider? And it doesn't seem to allow you to create new accounts.

Comment: VerifyPassword only requires a local password for your users. You could manually batch upload the testing accounts as illustrated by https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-python/blob/master/gitkit_command_tool.py.